# How to quote values of single column using group_concat and concat, distinct

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I need to use `group_concat` to build a list of comma separated values but I need the values to be quoted inside single quote. How to do this? The query which I have written doesn't work for me.
I have values inside column like this:

```
userid (column)

 1)   1,2
 2)   3,4
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT('\'', user_id, '\'') ) as listed_id
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT('''', user_id, '''') ) as listed_id
```

Expected output:

```
'1','2','3','4'
```

But I am getting values like this

```
'1,2,3,4'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, Its is working perfectly in my case:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT("'", REPLACE(user_id, "," , "','") , "'")) as listed_id FROM users
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: My pleasure brother

Comment: Neat workaround. But just to clarify for @Anonymous: `distinct` might not work as you expect (or maybe it does): if you have `1,2`, and `1,3` in your original table, you will still get `'1','2','1','3'`. `dictinct` will only refer to the complete entry (e.g. if you have `1,2` and `1,2`, you will get `'1','2'` only once).